# Solving matrix equations over a finite field

Tags: equation-solving, bugs, finite-fields

I'm afraid this question is trivial, but I have spent the last couple of hours trying to figure out what goes wrong without any luck.

Given the following:

```
CDim = 3;
ODim = 3;
INV1 = Array[XX, {2^ODim - 1, ODim}]
M1 = RandomInteger[1, {ODim, CDim}];
OEF = ConstantArray[0, {2^ODim - 1, CDim}];
PROD = INV1.M1;
```

I'd like to solve PROD = OEF over GF(2)

```
Solve[{PROD == OEF}, Flatten[INV1]]
```

returns the correct answer

```
{{XX[1, 1] -> 0, XX[1, 2] -> 0, XX[2, 1] -> 0, XX[2, 2] -> 0, 
  XX[3, 1] -> 0, XX[3, 2] -> 0, XX[4, 1] -> 0, XX[4, 2] -> 0, 
  XX[5, 1] -> 0, XX[5, 2] -> 0, XX[6, 1] -> 0, XX[6, 2] -> 0, 
  XX[7, 1] -> 0, XX[7, 2] -> 0}}
```

However, when I run

```
Solve[{PROD == OEF}, Flatten[INV1], Modulus -> 2]
```

I get:

```
Solve::naqs: True is not a quantified system of equations and inequalities.
Solve[{{{0, XX[1, 1] + XX[1, 2], XX[1, 2]}, {0, XX[2, 1] + XX[2, 2], 
     XX[2, 2]}, {0, XX[3, 1] + XX[3, 2], XX[3, 2]}, {0, 
     XX[4, 1] + XX[4, 2], XX[4, 2]}, {0, XX[5, 1] + XX[5, 2], 
     XX[5, 2]}, {0, XX[6, 1] + XX[6, 2], XX[6, 2]}, {0, 
     XX[7, 1] + XX[7, 2], XX[7, 2]}} == {{0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 
     0}, {0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0}}}, {XX[1, 1], 
  XX[1, 2], XX[1, 3], XX[2, 1], XX[2, 2], XX[2, 3], XX[3, 1], 
  XX[3, 2], XX[3, 3], XX[4, 1], XX[4, 2], XX[4, 3], XX[5, 1], 
  XX[5, 2], XX[5, 3], XX[6, 1], XX[6, 2], XX[6, 3], XX[7, 1], 
  XX[7, 2], XX[7, 3]}, Modulus -> 2].
```

Why?

Thank you.

**Update:** it seemingly has to do with variables not appearing in any of the equations. For instance,

```
Solve[{a + b + c == 0, 4 a + 2 b + c == 3, 9 a + b + c == 0}, {a, b, 
  c, d, e}, Modulus -> 2]
```

gives the same error, whereas

```
Solve[{a + b + c == 0, 4 a + 2 b + c == 3, 9 a + b + c == 0}, {a, b, 
  c, d, e}]
```

yields

```
{{c -> 41, b -> 26, a -> 18}, {c -> 41, b -> 53, a -> 45}}
```

Comment: Check the variable names. It looks like `INVC` is used in some places and `INV1` in others.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau Sorry, I pasted the wrong part of the code. Note that the code runs fine when I'm not solving the system mod 2.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is a bug in Solve that affects problems with non-zero modulus and at least 2 variables that do not appear in the system. Will be fixed in the next version of Mathematica.